# C++ how to write a game with parallel possesses that against each other(shared memories)

Tags: c++, memory-management, parallel-processing

One needed to write a game with player A (possibly through input, but restrict to automated code for simplicity) and player B.

A and B were say on a shared array array

```
int Map[100][100]
```

One way was to write a sequential code, which was not interesting at all. Especially, with the keyboard input, there might be "the stuck" and "the missed strikes".

An idea way to fully allow for computational power and simultaneous updates was to use parallel process for player A and player B, such as a parallel_for loop inside a while loop or a while loop inside a parallel_for loop.

However, this brought to another question about the shared memory usage as mentioned above. A way to went around it was to use fstream to set a longer delay time and to write and read to disk. But that obviously would cause troubles and possible crashes, as well as the delayed computational efficiencies. (Will references by array also cause trouble if the memories were accessed at the same time? or has that been taken care by the hardware design of the CPU-Memory bridges?)

How to write a game with parallel possesses that against each other with shared memories/arrays?

---

sudo language:

```
player_script(indices, ){while(condition){}}

main(){
parallel_for(ix){player_script(ix, );}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "parallel processes" ?  If so, do you really want separate processes which both access a shared memory region, or would a single process with multiple threads (which by definition share the same memory space) suffice?

Comment: Please provide an example of the computation done on this array. Which process writes what, why ? Which process read what, when ? As is, this question is impossible to answer